# $window.open triggers state change error event in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my web application, i am navigating to "EmailLetter" state to generate email letters for my clients. In this page, i have two buttons "Generate" & "Preview". "Generate" button click events works fine without any problem but "Preview" button is triggering state change error event even though it received success response from ajax service call. I am using below code snippet for "Preview" button click event

```
function openPreview(isValid) {
        if (isValid && validateForm(true)) {    
            webApi.previewDocument(previewRequest)
                  .then(function (response) {

                    if (response && response.PreviewUrl) {
                        $window.open(response.PreviewUrl);
                    } else {
                        notification.error("Unable to generate preview!");
                    }
                });
```

}
}

In the above code snippet, i am able to open preview url in a new window successfully but this statement is triggering state change error event after opening preview url in new window

```
$window.open(response.PreviewUrl);
```

Please refer to attached screen shot highlighting error event log i tracked in console window.

[image]

Please note that, my current state is showing as "abstract" and it is trying to navigate to the same state "EmailLetter". Kindly let me know if i can avoid this.

Sample plunker code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iqKSXsmIb86qtXMFKDa9?p=preview)

Comment: possibly a bug....can you reproduce in a minimal and verifiable example demo?

Comment: I have included a link to sample plunker code.